# windows 10 - pin default microsoft programs to start menu

Tags: windows-10, startmenu

I'm sorry to ask such a silly questions here, but you probably can reply more faster than Microsoft :) So, I'd like to pin the default "Calendar" app to the start menu on my new windows 10, but I can't. I can pin everything which is not default program like Microsoft Office, Google Chrome, etc... But I can't pin a lot of for example Calendar, Calculator, Mail and etc...

Am I silly or isn't it possible?

Thanks!

p.s: sorry for my grammar, but I'm not a native-speaker.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software technical support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able right click on any application and choose to pin to start menu.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply, but it doesn't work for me and I don't know why. If I click on the Calendar with the right mouse button, nothing happens. :/

Comment: Are you able to right-click anywhere else?  (Asking to ensure that it's not a mouse driver issue after upgrade to Windows 10.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried to restard my PC yesterday, but it didn't help me, but today it works. Interesting.... :D